# How to standardize rows in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset like:

```
value_last_1    value_last_2    value_last_3    value_last_4
53.40           91.29           106.56          34.71
131.92          81.53           70.57           31.82
0.00            0.00            21.27           12.55
```

It's easy to standardize the data set by columns using `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`. However, if I want to standardize by rows how can I do that without transposing the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can with pandas `mean` and `std`

```
df.sub(df.mean(1), axis=0).div(df.std(1), axis=0)
Out[841]: 
   value_last_1  value_last_2  value_last_3  value_last_4
0     -0.545272      0.596815      1.057086     -1.108629
1      1.283973      0.062308     -0.203409     -1.142872
2     -0.813624     -0.813624      1.233186      0.394061
```

Comment: when I calculated the standard deviation. I think pandas would use the sample standard deviation not the sd for Population. I have another problem like if all the values in 4 columns is the same so the standard deviation would be zero, and result would be NaN. Then I would use `.fillna` to fix that right?

Comment: @Homesand yes you can using `fillna`